# csv file convert to io.BytesIO object, then stream to blob storage ,meets value type error:a bytes-like object is required, not '_io.TextIOWrapper'

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure-blob-storage, bytesio, csvtoarray

I am trying to stream a csv  to azure blob storage, the csv is generated directly from python scripts without local copy, i have the following code, df is the csv file:

```
    with open(df,'w') as f:
       stream = io.BytesIO(f)
       stream.seek(0)
       block_blob_service.create_blob_from_stream('flowshop', 'testdata123', stream)
```

then i got the error massage:

```
  stream = io.BytesIO(f)  TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not '_io.TextIOWrapper'
```

i think the problem has been the format incorrect, can you please identify the problem. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You opened `df` for write, then tried to pass the resulting file object as the initializer of `io.BytesIO`  (which is supposed to to take actual binary data, e.g. `b'1234'`). That's the cause of the `TypeError`; open files (read or write, text or binary) are not `bytes` or anything similar (`bytearray`, `array.array('B')`, `mmap.mmap`, etc.), so passing them to `io.BytesIO` makes no sense.

<s>It looks like your goal is to *read* from `df`, and you shouldn't need `io.BytesIO` at all for that. Just change the mode from (text) write, `'w'`, to binary read, `'rb'`. Then pass the resulting file object to your API directly:</s>

```
with open(df, 'rb') as f:
   block_blob_service.create_blob_from_stream('flowshop', 'testdata123', f)
```

**Update:** Apparently `df` was your actual data, not a file name to open at all. Given that, you should really skip the stream API (which is pointless if the data is already in memory) and just use [the `bytes` based API](https://azure.github.io/azure-storage-python/ref/azure.storage.blob.blockblobservice.html#azure.storage.blob.blockblobservice.BlockBlobService.create_blob_from_bytes) directly:

```
block_blob_service.create_blob_from_bytes('flowshop', 'testdata123', df)
```

or if `df` is `str`, not `bytes`:

```
block_blob_service.create_blob_from_bytes('flowshop', 'testdata123', df.encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: hi, i did as your code, but after check the blob storage, the created testdata123 is a empty file ,,,,

Comment: @PepinPeng: Does whatever file is referenced by `df` have anything in it? Odds are it doesn't, since your previous code (which opened it for write) would have truncated it to an empty file as a side-effect of opening it (so even though the code failed immediately after, the data was already lost).

Comment: hi, thanks, but i have put a print (f) just before the blob API, and i got this print out as "<_io.BufferedReader name='WO,1,2,3,4\n1,600,300,400,500\n2,200,500,100,300\n3,100,500,200,300\n4,300,600,100,400\n'>"  that means after open as f, the data are still there , should i try write to it ?

Comment: @PepinPeng: Your `df` was the actual data, not a file name. That would have been useful to know initially. Given that, you don't need `open` at all. You want `block_blob_service.create_blob_from_stream('flowshop', 'testdata123', io.BytesIO(df))`, possibly `io.BytesIO(df.encode('utf-8'))` if `df` is a `str`. Or just skip the rigmarole, and use the API that accepts `bytes` directly: `create_blob_from_bytes('flowshop', 'testdata123', df)` (again, might need `df.encode('utf-8')` if `df` is `str`, not `bytes`).

Comment: i was struggling in the Shadow until i met your ShadowRanger, my whole days coding end with a success, thank you ,hahaha